# hash indexes - any workaround for searching large values

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongo, and I have a bit of a unique scenario.

Lets say we have a collection the documents with something like:

```
{date: ISODate(), text: "this is a large character field with over 1024 bytes"}
```

Lets imagine that we have 1 billion documents with 100,000 unique text values. It would be nice to normalize this data, but since mongo isn't relational, we're not doing that.

Other than the fact that this is taking up much more diskspace than necessary, it's not really causing any big problems. We have a hash index on text and as long as we know the specific text value we can pull records based off of it.

But what if we don't know the value? How can we find it? I am curious if there is any workaround to allow this.

For instance if we could do something like this, it would be useful. Is this possible?

```
var cursor = collection.myindex.find();

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    var hash = cursor.next().numberLong;
    var doc = db.collection.findOne({text: {$hash: hash}});
    print(doc.text);
}
```

Comment: I can not understand what are you trying to do. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: How do you find a document if you don't know the `text`? What do you know about it? How can you find anything if you know nothing about it? Can you give a specific example of what you're talking about? Your example code doesn't really make sense because there's no `numberLong` field in your example document and all the code does is find another document with the same text hash as the current one on the cursor, which is pretty pointless unless you have some other operation in mind to go with it.